# What is the difference between app.config file and XYZ.settings file?

Tags: .net, configuration, settings, appsettings

I am actually in the learning phase of .NET related stuff and I was exploring how to save the application. I ended up writing my own class which saves the settings in an XML file and then I found that .NET itself supports saving application settings.

But I found 2 ways to do that. When I open add new item dialog in Visual Studio 2008, it gives  option to create Settings file (.settings) or a configuration file (.config). Whats the difference between both and in what scenario they should be used?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

UPDATE: In ASP.NET Core Land, configuration is no longer managed via either of these - [see this fantastic writeup from Travis Illig with the a-z on `Microsoft.Extension.Configuration` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` which are effectively a superset of all this](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2018/06/20/microsoft-extensions-configuration-deep-dive/)

---

Settings (Both from a .settings set and `Configuration.AppSettings`), are stored in the .config file [alongside lots of other stuff].

The difference is that the .settings stuff [which was added in .NET 2.0 / VS2005] layers a strongly typed class on top of a set of settings that belong together whereas `Configuration.AppSettings` just lets you retrieve strings, forcing you to do any conversions, and doesnt have the notion of defaults. (the Configuration class has actually been shunted into a side assembly to reflect this - you need to add a reference to System.Configuration explicitly if you want it).

Adding a .settings to your project will result in an app.config being added to house the settings if you dont already have one. The class which reads the settings is automatically generated each time you change the list of settings for your component/application.

Other features of .Settings is the ability to designate some settings as user-specific (and also to save the user-specific settings with a single call).

The best reason of all to use .Settings is generally that you gain the ability to clearly identify who is using which setting in a code base by following usages of properties (and each set is a separate block in the XML file). `Configuration.appSettings` is more global in it's nature - it's just a bag of properties and you dont know which DLL, subsystem or class depends on a particular setting entry. See [this blog post from Steven Smith](http://ardalis.com/applying-interface-segregation-to-configuration-files) for much more.

Finally, if you still haven't read enough about settings management, you're not going to beat [this Rick Strahl post on the subject](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/RickStrahl/~3/I41oCo7CAW4/Building-a-better-NET-Application-Configuration-Class-revisited) for completeness or sheer quantities of ideas and angles.

ASIDE: There's also the [ASP.NET vNext Configuration](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration) stuff, [outlined in this article](http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/) which is quite flexible and offers a different angle on configuration settings management.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just confused about one point: There are 2 type of settings. One is app setting and other is user setting. If both types of settings are stored in config file, how will user settings be different for different users?

Comment: Sorry for omitting mention of that.  User settings is one of the reason why defaults exist (if the user hasnt used the app yet, the defaults apply until a change is saved).  The user settings are stored in a separate configuration file in the user's profile (Users\XXX) directory.  User settings can be updated too (System ones cannot be using the default API and should not - they live in Program Files and it's not possible to securely control multiple user access to there.)

Comment: where does configuration manager fit into all this?  Im trying and failing to get that to tell me where my settings.settings lives and then save a blank config there

Comment: @JonnyLeeds Not sure what you mean so I'll try to expand to see if it helps you.... Your `.settings` file just defines the schema and gets compiled into a codebehind. The actual values live in the `.config` file which will be in a user profile dir (non-user ones are not writeable). The data lives in the same place as `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` puts it,  it's just in a custom format with stronger typing. You can do things like `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal ).FilePath` but before I tell you that.... why?

Comment: @RubenBartelink thanks for the response.  That's pretty much the conclusion I came to - just posted a Q&A to document my pain [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089417/how-do-you-write-out-a-blank-version-of-your-config-when-a-program-is-first-run?noredirect=1)!

Comment: Also see [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072966/199364).

Answer (score 5):

A settings file is a resource file in which you specify the different settings and their default value.

The values themselves are configured in the application configuration file (.config file).

A settings file is never deployed, so you will need the config file to do the configuration.

Comment: While I'm in picky mode (just updated my own post - lots missing in there) While a .settings file is an XML file, I'm reasonably sure it's not bolund in as a Resource, is it? Also, user-specific values get stored in a separate area, outside of the .config file. The .config file needs to be deployed if you've got non-default settings (attributes within the generated settings class manage the defaulting of the values if nothing is specified in the config file.)

Comment: While the Settings.settings xml file isn't deployed, the Settings.Designer.cs file gets compiled into the application, doesn't it?

Answer (score -1):

The app.config file is stored in the same directory as the app. Normal users will not have write permissions (e.g. in "Program Files").

The settings file should be stored in the users "AppData" directory (where he has r/w permissions).

So use the settings file for user configurable options.

Comment: Not quite right, according to other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/909712/199364 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072966/199364 `.settings` (and Visual Studio's `Settings` support) can be used both for one-time application config and per-user config. `.settings` doesn't exist at run-time; what exists at run-time is `app.config` in app folder, and [user] `.config` in user's data folder.