# Settings.settings vs app.config?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, app-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between app.config file and XYZ.settings file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909688/what-is-the-difference-between-app-config-file-and-xyz-settings-file)

Whats the big difference here? I like to use Settings.Settings because og the editor and dont get all the xml in app.config.

Comment: If your going to use the app.config you better get used to editing xml files.

Comment: Hope below similar threads help. The biggest difference I see is Settings can be used to store user specific information while app.config is mainly for application related configurations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909688/what-is-the-difference-between-app-config-file-and-xyz-settings-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539460/settings-file-vs-app-config [What is the difference between Settings.settings and web.config or app.config?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1473428.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings.settings is the designer file for Visual Studio to generate the settings class like how .resx files hold resources.

The settings have to be stored somewhere, but they aren't stored in Settings.settings (the default ones are). They are stored in .config files.

With the generated class, you can update the app.config and not worry about manipulating the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the environment values (like connection strings section) in Settings file, because they are unprotected there. Also settings in app.config can't be set from Settings file, so, in some time, you'll have to use both files.