# Can't read from app.config using Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, properties, app-config

I'm trying to read from my AppConfig but it's not working.

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="Console.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<userSettings>
    <Console.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="LogFiles" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
    </Console.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Program.cs:

```
namespace Console
{
class Console
{
    public static readonly bool LogFiles = Properties.Settings. //Cant find symbol Default
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
}
```

When using Properties.Settings i Can't find the Default symbol or LogFiles property. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to use Application-level settings or User-level settings stored in App.config?

Comment: @krillezzz app.config will be copied with the executable. Because of this if would be impossible to have 2 or more user specific settings with single installation.

Comment: @Jarlax I'm not really follow now..I have only one value with user specific level

Comment: @krillezzz Sorry for being not 100% clear. My point is that by design in `app.config` you can have only application level settings, not the user level settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatic way to achieve this is to use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]` instead. Config will look like:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LogFiles" value="True" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And retrieval of application setting would be:

```
bool logFiles = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFiles"]);
```

Comment: Why is this better? I've done it that way, but I thought this was more cleaner in code

Comment: In this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13101547/4430998) there is short comparison of Settings vs app.config. If the requirement is to have user specific settings, then they should be not defined in app.config.