# When is Settings.cs created?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

For a C# .NET 4.5 application in Visual Studio 2012 (or any .NET and VS version), when is Settings.cs created or first referenced?

I use Settings.cs to retrieve some user preferences on program startup and to store them when the program exits. I once forgot to put Settings.cs under version control and when a user grabbed my branch and ran the .exe from bin\debug or \release he got a popup error message related to the missing file that didn't come back the second time he ran the program.

Is Settings.cs even automatically created or must it be provided with the solution? If so, can it be generated with code?

Comment: Are you actually reading the `.cs` file from your code at run time?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Good point. No, I'm just looking at the variables within Settings.settings (or Properties.Settings.Default through the code).

Comment: Why not use app.config?

Comment: @AndrewCooper, because app.config isn't designed to store user settings, since it can't be modified by the process that uses it (at least not easily). Settings.settings, OTOH, exists precisely for this purpose.

Comment: @AndrewCooper "Adding a .settings to your project will result in an app.config being added to house the settings if you dont already have one" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909688/what-is-the-difference-between-app-config-file-and-xyz-settings-file

Comment: Cool.  I learned something new.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is created (or re-created) automatically whenever you save the `Settings.settings` file (which happens, for instance, when you edit the settings via the project's property pages)